# Mockito 'misplaced argument detected' error inside "when" method

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mockito

I am attempting to mock a call to a spy object and keep getting an `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException`.

The method call mocking is as follows:

```
@Spy
private AmazonS3Client m_clientToMockServer;

// (...)

Mockito.when(m_clientToMockServer.listObjects(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString()))
            .thenAnswer((Answer<ObjectListing>) invocation -> {
                ObjectListing objectListing = (ObjectListing) invocation.callRealMethod();
                objectListing.setMaxKeys(2);
                return objectListing;
            });
```

The error message says:

> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>
> Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>
> ```
> when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
> doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
> verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
> ```
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

I've checked that `AmazonS3Client.listObjects(String, String)` is not final nor private, so I can only imagine I might be actually using the parameter matching wrong. And in fact, if I use any other actual string instead of the `Mockito.anyString()` matchers, this code snippet works.

Comment: doReturn().when()... https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Comment: Can you provide the smallest possible complete class that reproduces this problem, instead of just a snippet?

Comment: @JBNizet nailed it. Quoting the important part of the link he provided: 

_Sometimes it's impossible or impractical to use when(Object) for stubbing spies. Therefore when using spies please consider doReturn|Answer|Throw() family of methods for stubbing._